# Using Paraller.Foreach with partitioner in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, partitioner

i'm building a custom plugin for Unity GameEngine which supports .NET 3.5 And to be able to use TPL i installed the Reactive Extensions v1.0.2856.0 (i think is the last that includes TPL). So, in a script i have a loop with about 65000 interations. I have no problem using the Parallel.Foreach loop for example, but the problem is that with the default partitioner the work is not distributed equally because of the small count of iterations and actually the loop gets a bit slower.

So my questions is:
Is there a way to create a partitioner which gives to my 2 CPU cores about half of the iterations to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var options = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2};
Parallel.ForEach(list, options,
    item =>
    {
        // work})
    });
```

Comment: that actually helps a bit, the work is distributed much better like 2/3 for the 1st core and 1/3 for the second core and there is slight boost in performance about +5%... is there something else i could try to boost the loop? something with partitioneres as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.100).aspx    as i understand there is a difference is the System.Collections.Concurrent assembly in 4.0 and 3.5

Comment: Parallel by default, already does a pretty good job of distributing the work between cores. Maybe some of your items are taking longer to process than others?

Comment: The loop represents a Ray-Triangle Intersection testing and each iteration should have the same cost. May be the problem is that even 65000 iterations are to little for parallel loop. It finishes in 0.01 ms on the main thread and probably the cost of creating new thread is big. I just try to guess while reading the docs in MSDN.